# Prevent Diazo from escaping ampersands within an attribute

Tags: plone, diazo

I am using a template with the following TAL:

```
<iframe tal:attributes="src view/src" />
```

where view.src returns a URL including a query string with ampersands.

The template renders this fine, but after going through Diazo the ampersands are escaped as &amp;

How can I prevent Diazo from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is returning invalid HTML - outside of the CDATA script and style tags, ampersands should be encoded as entities (http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp). The HTMLParser can guess what you mean, but the serializer encodes the data correctly on the way out and there is not way to avoid that.

Note that this is just the HTML encoding of data, to take an example:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com?foo=1&amp;baz=2" />
```

The *value*  of the iframe's src attribute is `http://example.com?foo=1&baz=2`.

Comment: Then my problem is that I need to serve invalid HTML in order for IE to load the correct value for the URL.

Comment: At least in IE7 the following works: ``<html><body><a href="http://shuttlethread.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2">test me</a></body></html>``

Comment: The only reference I could find to this problem in a quick search that did not involve double escaping was http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200812/accidental_html_entities_in_urls.html - and that involved javascript. Maybe try cutting this down to a minimal reproducible example html file.

You could output the html open and close tags manually using ``<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="..."/>`` in a ``<replace content="iframe">`` though maybe just replacing ``&`` with ``;`` would do the trick.

Comment: Turns out our partner was wrong and IE was interpreting the link correctly (which I proved using a proxy server to log what it was requesting).